# How can I check latest available version of Symfony with any API?

Tags: api, symfony, composer-php

I want to get **latest available** version of `Symfony Framework`. Can I get it with any available `API` (maybe with `Composer` or any web services)?

Comment: I would scrap this page to get the last LTS, stable and dev versions : http://symfony.com/roadmap

Comment: @Veve Does Symfony not provide any API for it? I won't parse html page for get latest available version (

Comment: Didn't found one... Agree with you, it's not a really good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official Symfony roadmap API can give you the most recent LTS, Stable, and Beta versions available.

Making a call to

```
https://symfony.com/roadmap.json?version=all
```

Will return something similar to

```
{
  "symfony_versions": {
    "lts": "2.8.5",
    "stable": "3.0.5",
    "beta": "3.1.0-DEV"
  },
  "latest_stable_version": "3.0",
  "version": "all",
  "error_message": "Wrong version format (should be X.Y or X.Y.Z where X, Y, and Z are integers)."
}
```

Note that this is an undocumented use of the API, as you trick it by not supplying a valid version number. This prompts the API to return a JSON object listing the current versions. Although undocumented, I think you can safely use this because the Symfony project has a strong history of maintaining backwards compatibility.

Comment: Wow, don't know it! It's awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[packagist.org](https://packagist.org/) actually has an undocumented API. All you have to do is go to any package page and add `.json` to the URL.

For example, this is the page for [symfony/symfony](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/symfony) and its respective [JSON formatted version](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/symfony.json).

The path `"package"->"versions"` is an object whose keys are version numbers and whose values are package description objects. These have a `version_normalized` key that you could use to sort the packages to find the latest version.

```
 "package": {
    "name": "symfony/symfony",
    "description": "The Symfony PHP framework",
    "time": "2011-09-29T17:29:54+00:00",
    "maintainers": [
      {
        "name": "fabpot"
      }
    ],
    "versions": {
      ...
      "v2.5.8": {
      "name": "symfony/symfony",
      "description": "The Symfony PHP framework",
      "keywords": [
        "framework"
      ],
      "homepage": "http://symfony.com",
      "version": "v2.5.8",
      "version_normalized": "2.5.8.0",
      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Packagist is your friend (that's where the composer stuff comes from)
https://packagist.org

https://packagist.org/feeds/package.symfony/symfony.rss
https://packagist.org/feeds/package.symfony/symfony.atom

**EDIT**

2nd solution is via github API
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/releases

more infos at https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-tags

Comment: I think with [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-tags) I can do this with a bit own code, Thanks!